# LESS: Mixin with a unique argument to manage css3 transitions

Tags: less, mixins

Using LESS CSS, I would like to simplify my code using Mixins to put "out" transitions declarations, but the following syntax is wrong. The problem is in the attribute `@color-time` definition that has 2 arguments:

```
.links-transition (@color-time:color 1s, border-color 1s)
{
  -webkit-transition:@color-time;
     -moz-transition:@color-time;
      -ms-transition:@color-time;
       -o-transition:@color-time;
          transition:@color-time;
}

a
{
  color:red;
  .links-transition;
}
```

In official documentation I found that putting a `;` at the end, teach LESS how to consider arguments, considering them separated by `;`, so one argument in my case like this:

```
.links-transition (@color-time:color 1s, border-color 1s;)
```

Unfortunately this does not run. I think it depends since white space... is there a correct syntax to obtain the correct CSS without using 2 arguments in Mixin recall?

Thank you.

Comment: Just answered [a similar question here with a multiple input allowed, flexible way of handling transitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412643/can-i-define-a-less-mixin-to-generate-a-transition-property-with-a-variable-numb/20810461#20810461).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**string escaping and interpolation**](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation) like this:

```
.links-transition (@arg:"color 1s, border-color 1s") {
  @color-time: ~"@{arg}";
  -webkit-transition:@color-time;
     -moz-transition:@color-time;
      -ms-transition:@color-time;
       -o-transition:@color-time;
          transition:@color-time;
}

a {
  color:red;
  .links-transition ("color 2s, border-color 2s");
}
```

it will return this **CSS**:

```
a {
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s, border-color 2s;
  -moz-transition: color 2s, border-color 2s;
  -ms-transition: color 2s, border-color 2s;
  -o-transition: color 2s, border-color 2s;
  transition: color 2s, border-color 2s;
}
```

hope this does what you want.

**For more ideas:** there are some additinal approaches/solutions that you can find on SO, like this two for example:

- [Less CSS: Mixins with Variable Number of Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419741/less-css-mixins-with-variable-number-of-arguments/11552717#11552717)
- [Multiple properties are getting treated as separate arguments in mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510568/multiple-properties-are-getting-treated-as-separate-arguments-in-mixins/13490523#13490523)

---

### Update: in LESS 1.4 beta it works the way you wanted to do it:

```
.links-transition (@color-time: color 1s, border-color 1s;) {
  -webkit-transition:@color-time;
     -moz-transition:@color-time;
      -ms-transition:@color-time;
       -o-transition:@color-time;
          transition:@color-time;
}

a {
  color:red;
  .links-transition (color 2s, border-color 2s;);
}
```

has the same output as the above solution. **Comma separated argunets are possible since 1.3.2, however they can apparently not include whitespaces.**