# LESS: Declare same properties for 2 mixins

Tags: less, mixins

In pure CSS if I want to declare the same property for 2 selectors, it's sufficient to separate these selectors with a comma such as:

```
#first_id,
.second_class
{
   color:red;
}
```

How can I make the same thing for 2 LESS Mixins declaration?

I would like to make something like this:

```
.generic_transition (@duration:1s),
.other_transition (@duration:1s)
{
  -webkit-transition:all @duration;
     -moz-transition:all @duration;
      -ms-transition:all @duration;
       -o-transition:all @duration;
          transition:all @duration;
}
```

But it does not run.... How to reach expected result?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add helper class for every mixin like this:

```
.other_transition (@duration:1s){
  .helper(@duration);
}

.generic_transition (@duration:1s){
  .helper(@duration); 
}

.helper(@duration){
  -webkit-transition:all @duration;
     -moz-transition:all @duration;
      -ms-transition:all @duration;
       -o-transition:all @duration;
          transition:all @duration;
}
```

Comment: In this way... You're suggesting to use a sort of "temp" mixin to solve my problems in 2 steps... Am I correct?

Comment: yes, i think, better to use only one mixin: .generic_transition (@duration:1s) or .other_transition (@duration:1s)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Slawa's answer, but slightly less code. Since one of your names for mixins is already `.generic_transition`, then this works and is clear that `.other_transition` uses the `generic` transition's code:

```
.generic_transition (@duration:1s) {
  -webkit-transition:all @duration;
     -moz-transition:all @duration;
      -ms-transition:all @duration;
       -o-transition:all @duration;
          transition:all @duration;
}

.other_transition (@duration:1s) {
    .generic_transition (@duration);
}
```

It is unclear, however, why you would want two mixins defined exactly the same, as your original question has. That makes sense for selectors, but not as much for mixins. I'm assuming you want to set up some "generic" code for transitions, and then have that applied "generically" to any "other" transition.

Also, while your question does not necessarily deal with transitions, since that is what you used as an example, then [this answer may prove useful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412643/can-i-define-a-less-mixin-to-generate-a-transition-property-with-a-variable-numb/20810461#20810461).