# How to loop through all params in Less mixin

Tags: less

I'm writing a Less mixin.

I want to be able to pass the mixin several parameters. The first will be a string. The rest, an infinite number of parameters, will be value pairs.

In my mixin how can I loop through the infinite number of parameters?

For example one time I will call...

```
.my-mixin(@name, @foo: bar, @hello: world);
```

and another time...

```
.my-mixin(@name, @iam: cool, @youare: lame, @someoneis: awesome);
```

Here's what it would look like if Less supported JS/PHP...

```
.my-mixin() {
    @name: @arguments[0]; //First param

    for (@arguments as @label => @value) {
        @label: @value;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See [Mixing Arguments](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-advanced-arguments-and-the-rest-variable), [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature), [List Functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) and all the loop examples [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bless%5d%20loop%20.-each) at [**SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bless%5d%20loop). The rest (i.e. code in the loop body) depends on how you need to render supplied values to CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop over an array of name value pairs in LESS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658087/loop-over-an-array-of-name-value-pairs-in-less)

Answer (score 1):

In fact you ask two questions. First how to create a mixin that can accept an endless number of parameters, and secondly who to iterate over the list / array of parameters.

Less has the special `...` syntax to create mixins with an endless number of parameters. The official documentation can be found here: [Advanced arguments and the @rest variable](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-advanced-arguments-and-the-rest-variable). An example / use case can be found at [Can I define a LESS mixin to generate a transition-property with a variable number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412643/can-i-define-a-less-mixin-to-generate-a-transition-property-with-a-variable-numb).

The special `...` syntax can be used to assign the parameter list to a variable by adding the variable name before the `...`:

```
.mixin(@parameter1, @endlesslistofparameters...) {}
```

The @endlesslistofparameters variable now contains a list of parameters, you can use the [Less list functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) to extract a value from this list (or find its length):
`length()` returns the length of a list and `extract(@list,position)` return the value of a certain position in the list. Notice that the first value is on position `1` and not `0`.

Finally you can use a loop to iterate over this list of arguments.

> In Less a mixin can call itself. Such recursive mixins, when combined
>   with Guard Expressions and Pattern Matching, can be used to create
>   various iterative/loop structures.

See also:  [Loop over an array of name value pairs in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658087/loop-over-an-array-of-name-value-pairs-in-less)

All together i think you can write something like that shown below:

```
.my-mixin(@name,@properties...) {
.setproperties(@iterator:1) when (@iterator <= length(@properties)) {
@propertyname: extract(extract(@properties,@iterator),1);
@{propertyname}: extract(extract(@properties,@iterator),2);
.setproperties((@iterator + 1));
}
.@{name} {
.setproperties();
}
}

.my-mixin(jared; iam cool, youare lame, someoneis awesome);
```

The preceding Less code will compile into the following CSS code:

```
.jared {
  iam: cool;
  youare: lame;
  someoneis: awesome;
}
```

And than also notice that Less allows you to [Passing Rulesets to Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) since version 1.7, which enables you to write:

```
.my-mixin2(@name,@properties) {
.@{name} {
@properties();
}
}
.my-mixin2(jared; {iam: cool; youare: lame; someoneis: awesome;});
```